# Firebug showing "Debugger is already active" error message after update 1.6.0?

Tags: firebug

After the last Firebug update 1.6.0 I keep getting this error message when debugging (under the "Script" tab):

> Debugger is already active
>
> The debugger is currently halted at a
>   breakpoint on another page. Go to that
>   page

Okay, but "Go to that page" doesn't bring me anywhere and I can't seem to debug anything. I only have a single instance of Firefox running, restarting it doesn't help the issue ... even uninstalling the add-on and reinstalling it doesn't do anything. Is there anyway to remove the breakpoints from the command line, what's going on here?

Edit: Going back to 1.5.x solves the problems, but even going up to 1.7.x alpha reproduces the problem, I'd file a bug report, but if I'm the only one experiencing it, it isn't much of a bug.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. Have you filed a bug for this?

Comment: I have the same problem with Firebug 1.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We believe that this problem is fixed for Firebug 1.6.1; 1.6.1b1 is available at http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug

I'd really like to hear more bug reports on this particular problem. This is probably an extension conflict, so we need folks to post the result of url "about:support" so we can compare the lists or we need you to try installing Firebug in a new Firefox profile then adding extensions until you find the problem. (I doubt jQuery is involve or we would catch it in beta testing).

See also 
http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3724
http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3719

jjb

Comment: Opened a bug: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3769

user500038, please attach your about:support.

Answer (score 3):

My workaround: go to [profile directory](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles) and delete firebug/breakpoints.json.

Firebug 1.6.1 on Firefox 3.6.13 on MacOS 10.6. Tried disabling all other extensions and had no luck.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) Firebug 1.6.1 Firefox 3.6.13 Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 0):

Highly suspect. Espionage is what I get.  Other suspect Firebug Script window messages.

```
> No Javascript on this page
> 
> If <script> tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal
> "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be
> parsable (syntactically correct).


> System sources can't be debugged
> 
> Firebug currently can't be used to debug user agent internal files.
> See issue 5110 for the reason. You may use the DevTools Browser
> Toolbox instead.
```